# Spark -- performance impact on join with multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Currently we have to consider use case to join many columns (may be 20-30 or even more) between two dataframes to identify new rows to persist.

One dataframe can contain 200k rows and the other 40k rows but can keep growing.

we run the process in cluster, roughly 40 worker nodes..

so the question is not about can spark do it, but not paralyze the entire cluster

The question from this scenario:

1. How cluster performance differ based on numbers of columns to join (reshuffle etc)?
2. Is it practical to partition the dataframe across all the joining columns?